# jshint Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'

Tags: javascript, npm

My `grunt` task seems to be running perfectly fine, but every time I run it I'm getting this error:

```
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
```

Is there any way to find out why this is happening? I can see the `/grunt-contrib-jshint` directory is in the `/node_modules` directory. Is there any reason it can't find the `underscore` module? I've tried running `npm install` but I still get the same error when I run grunt.

Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you have `cannot find module x` errors, one thing that might help sometimes is deleting the whole `npm_modules` folder and just running `npm install` again. Sometimes, on the initial `npm install`, it might of failed to get one dependency for a package and it won't try to get it again when you run `npm install` again, as it got all of the packages you wanted, just maybe not all the dependencies of those packages.

Comment: @jValdron Thanks for the tip. That worked a treat!

Comment: Posted an answer so you can accept it and "close" this question :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you have `cannot find module x errors`, one thing that might help sometimes is deleting the whole `npm_modules` folder and just running `npm install` again.

Sometimes, on the initial `npm install`, it might of failed to get one dependency for a package and it won't try to get it again when you run `npm install` again, as it got all of the packages *you* wanted, just maybe not all the dependencies of those packages.

Comment: Agree, worked for me too. I was getting similar error:
`Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'cli'`

Comment: For me the folder is called `node_modules` not `npm_modules` (magento 2)

Answer (score 5):

you can use `npm update`
I test this command and this answer.

Comment: This worked for me too. seemed that the package.lock file was from a older version of NPM and needed to updated.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

```
npm update
npm install underscore
```

If that doesn't work do the following.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install -d
npm update
```

Comment: npm install underscore worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento 2, then make sure that you did not accidentially deleted the file "package.json". If the file exist, then execute:

```
npm remove -g grunt grunt-cli && npm install -g grunt grunt-cli && npm install grunt --save-dev && npm install
```

Then you can test with

```
grunt refresh
```